# How to trim fetched video in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I fetch a video from a server, and then I need to trim the first 2 seconds of it. I don't have a backend (I know the way using node.js), but I have to do it in the frontend.

I added #t=2 to the end of the request, but that doesn't work.

I use React, this is my code:

```
<video src='http://193.70.82.68/video/bigbang/s08-kuraj/01.mp4#t=2' controls />
```